# Double is not stored correctly in MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an MVC application which has a restful service that updates latitude and longitude to the database. I am sending the values to the API as string and its converted to Double before it is stored in database as Double. Here is the code I am using to convert string to double:

```
Double _latitude, _longitude;
try
{
     Double.TryParse(lattitude, NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out _latitude);
     Double.TryParse(Longtitude, NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out _longitude);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     _latitude = 0;
     _longitude = 0;
}
```

When its stored in database I am missing decimal points. For example:

> 53.345634 is stored as 53345634

**I have this working on development environment running on Windows 2012. But when its moved to Windows 2008 production server I am seeing this issue.**

Comment: Depending on your MySQL version, you might want to try to change the data type to decimal or float. I know it doesn't make much sense, but from my experience it may be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specifying correct IFormatProvider/CultureInfo**

The behavior that you observed might be caused by the fact that two machines have different [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx)s. Default value of `CurrentCulture` depends on a version of Windows.

To get consistent results across various machines, you should provide a specific `CultureInfo` (or any other class implementing `IFormatProvider`) for Parse or TryParse method, e.g.

```
// using System.Globalization;
double value = Double.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
double valueUsEnglish = Double.Parse(stringValue, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

[Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx) method uses a *culture-specific decimal point symbol* and *group-separator symbol*. In some languages (e.g. in English) decimal point symbol is a dot whereas in others (e.g. in Polish) it's a comma. Group-separator symbols are also different in various languages.

If `53.345634` is parsed as `53345634`, your computer uses a culture where dot is a group-separator.

**Parse vs TryParse**

You should also think whether using `Parse` of `TryParse` method is more appropriate.

If during normal operation your program expects invalid output (e.g. it a user-provided value), you should definitely use `TryParse` and inspect returned value. `TryParse` returns a bool indicating whether parsing was successful and doesn't throw exceptions.

If the value that you are parsing should never be wrong (e.g. you are parsing resources that bounded with your program) you can use `Parse`. If you have some way to recover or provide some additional information to the user, you can catch appropriate exceptions. According to documentation possible exceptions are: `ArgumentNullException`,  `FormatException` and `OverflowException`.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the dqta type in the 2008 db is decimal and not int

Comment: In 2008 DB its Double which is same as in Development DB

Comment: This is a comment to the original question, not an answer. When you've earned the comment privilege (in about another six points rep), you'll be able to leave comments. It's not appropriate to use the Answer space in the meantime.